# Андроид SQL выборка

Tags: android, sql

Есть БД “People” с двумя столбцами NAME и RANK
Я делаю выборку по первому столбцу NAME с аргументом “Tom” в listview:

```
db = databaseHelper.open(); 
userCursor = db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “ =? “, new String[] {“Tom”} );

String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK};
userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter ( this, android.R.layout.two_Line_List_item,
userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.text1,android.R.id.text2}, 0);
userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);}
```

И это работает.

НО когда я пытаюсь сделать выборку по обоим столбцам NAME и RANK :

```
db=databaseHelper.open(); 
userCursor=db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “=?” + “ and “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + “ =? “, new String[] {“Tom”, “Junior”} );

String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK};
userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter ( this, android.R.layout.two_Line_List_item,
userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.text1,android.R.id.text2}, 0);
userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);}
```

Listview пустой, и не заполняется.
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: попробуйте во втором примере проставить одинаковые (не парные) кавычки

Comment: Может Тома юниора нет в таблице?

Comment: С одинарными кавычками подчеркивает красным и предлогает поменять на двойные, увы.

Comment: Я вас уверяю том юниор там есть и не один )

Comment: И даже с большой буквы `J`? (намёк на чувствительность к регистру). Сама константа `DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK` - точно имеет нужное значение?

Comment: я говорил не про одинарные, а про одинаковые. Приглядитесь к этому `“` и к этому `”`

Comment: userCursor=db.rawQuery("select *from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + " where " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + "=?" + " and " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + " =? ", new String[] {"Tom", "Junior"} );

Comment: С этими кавычками результат тот же, пустой список.

Comment: Регистр учтен, все элементы есть в базе.

Comment: Тогда смотрите внимательно логи на предмет `Exceptions`. И показывайте больше кода - запрос выглядит рабочим, значит проблема не в нём, а где-то  на пути к экрану.

Comment: Вместо знака '=' используйте 'like'

Comment: Вы ищите таким запросом Тома Жуниора. Уверены, что такой есть и это то, что вы хотите найти?

Comment: Woesss.    Exeption отсутсвуют, я обновил код в вопросе.

Comment: Vitaly.  Like дает тот же результат как и =

Comment: Тоm Junior есть, иначе зачем тогда мне его искать?

Comment: Делая поиск, по Tom Junior, или по всем Томам из колонки name, и всем джуниорам (независимо от имени) в колонке ранк, работает только если белать выборку по какойто одной колонке, но если пытатся делать выборку из двух разных колонок то листвью не заполняется

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем ошибка, забыл поставить
`userCursor.moveToNext();`  в конце
И “or” вместо “and”

```
db = databaseHelper.open();
userCursor=db.rawQuery(“select *from “ + DatabaseHelper.TABLE + “ where “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + “=?” + “ or  “ + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_RANK + “ =? “,
new String[] {“Tom”, “Junior”} );
userCursor.moveToNext();
```